# Problems with selecting 2 column values in Linq to Entity

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

Hi I am trying to select the values of two columns which are second driver and price but I am getting error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Below is the code:

```
 public IQueryable<Event> GetSecondDriverOption(int eventID)
 {
     ApextrackdaysEntities entity = new ApextrackdaysEntities();
     IQueryable<Event> SecondDriver = from p in entity.Events
                                      where p.ID == eventID
                                      select new{ p.SecondDriver,
                                                  p.SecondDriverPrice};
     return SecondDriver;
 }
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use projection when you expect `IQueryable<Event>` where `Event` is your mapped type. You must either select `Event` :

```
IQueryable<Event> SecondDriver = from p in entity.Events
                                 where p.ID == eventID
                                 select p;
```

Or you must create new type and project data to a new type:

```
public class EventDto
{
    public Driver SecondDriver { get; set; }
    public Price SecondDriverPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and redefine your method:

```
public IQueryable<EventDto> GetSecondDriverOption(int eventID)
{
    ApextrackdaysEntities entity = new ApextrackdaysEntities();
    IQueryable<EventDto> SecondDriver = from p in entity.Events
                                        where p.ID == eventID
                                        select new EventDto 
                                            {
                                                SecondDriver = p.SecondDriver,
                                                SecondDriverPrice = p.SecondDriverPrice
                                            };
    return SecondDriver;
}
```

Comment: The class EventDto which you have used , is it custom shaped View model class .

Comment: Call it like you want. It is class which allows you selecting only two columns / properties and return them from the method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return anonymous objects. Try like this:

```
public IQueryable<Event> GetSecondDriverOption(int eventID)
{
    ApextrackdaysEntities entity = new ApextrackdaysEntities();
    var seconDriver = 
           from p in entity.Events
           where p.ID == eventID;
           select p;
    return secondDriver;
}
```

Comment: but I want both the columns not just seconddriver

Comment: so can i do something like secondDriver.price , viceversa in controller by call this class

Comment: @Muhammad Awais, you should use a view model, so that the controller queries the data and fills this view model which will be passed to the view. This view model will contain the properties required by your view.

Comment: You mean custom shaped View model class..?

Comment: @Muhammad Awais, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Have you got ny examples of it online, i just went trhough professional mvc2 book , i cant find ny example there , dey have just explained what custom shaped model class is ...